# Difference between sw600dp and w600dp?

Tags: android, layout

Please elaborate on the difference between `sw<N>dp` and `w<N>dp`, in a simple way. I have studied the complete documentation of screen sizes but am confused between these two qualifiers **sw<>** and **w<>**.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Android device screens are rectangles. Rectangles have two sides, one shorter than the other. Let's call the short one A and the long one B.

`-swNNNdp` indicates "use these resources if A is greater than or equal to NNN `dp` in length"

`-wNNNdp` indicates "use these resources if the width of the device, as presently held, is greater than or equal to NNN `dp`"

When the user rotates the device between portrait and landscape, the width will change (to be A or B), but A (the shortest width) is always the same.

Comment: for example a device that have 600dp smallest width and use rotate device to portrait still the layout use sw600dp resource?

Comment: @MudassarShaheen: Correct.

Comment: kindly tell me one thing more. if device has 320x480 mdpi  density means it will use resource from w320dp am i right? and if user switch orientation to landscape now it have to pick resource from w480 dp?

Comment: @MudassarShaheen: "am i right?" -- both sides are 320dp or larger, but what resource set is used depends on what resource sets are available. "and if user switch orientation to landscape now it have to pick resource from w480 dp?" -- if such a resource set exists, yes.

Comment: thanks for your helping me do u have any sample project which cover these things ?

Comment: @MudassarShaheen: Not presently, though I should be adding some in the next month or two. I was waiting for more devices to be running a version of Android that actually honors these types of resource sets.

Comment: Can anybody tell me, is there any practical scenario where I should use both sw600dp and w600dp at same time?

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please answer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58554897/dimens-xml-for-multi-window-mode-in-android

Answer (score 14):

Please take a look at [Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

According to the documentations :

**SW** : The fundamental size of a screen, as indicated by the shortest dimension of the available screen area. Specifically, the device's smallestWidth is the shortest of the screen's available height and width (you may also think of it as the "smallest possible width" for the screen). You can use this qualifier to ensure that, regardless of the screen's current orientation, your application's has at least  dps of width available for it UI.

while **W** : Specifies a minimum available width in dp units at which the resources should be used—defined by the  value. The system's corresponding value for the width changes when the screen's orientation switches between landscape and portrait to reflect the current actual width that's available for your UI.

In my words :

**SW** : minimum distance between screen edges in dps your layout will run on, so if you use layout-sw600dp/ folder then all layouts inside it will only work on devices that has at least 600dp (width or height)

**W** : means your layout will work on any device with n dp width regardless of the height or maybe the device currently in landscape mode (in this case w would refer to the height .. since orientation differs between landscape and portrait)

Comment: if device has 320x480 mdpi density means it will use resource from w320dp am i right? and if user switch orientation to landscape now screen width is 480dp it have to pick resource from w480 dp?

Comment: exactly .. btw the documentations discuss a lot of examples to make those values more clear

Comment: please let me know if i've to make 7 inch tablet (1280*800 resolution) app in ladscape mode , then should i prefer layout-sw600dp or layout-w600dp or layout-w600dp-land ?