# Load different resources depending on aspect ratio

Tags: android

My Android app's welcome screen would look like the one shown below.

[image: denko on phone]

However, I also need to support tablets which have wider screen. This unfortunately leaves little room for the logo at the bottom of the screen.

[image: denko on tablet]

I either need to crop the top and bottom of the background image a little or make the logo smaller if I detect a widescreen device.

How do I know if a device is widescreen? How do I crop images at runtime? Can I ask Android to load an alternative resource depending on screen aspect ratio? Can this be done using xml files without resorting to doing things programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can define different layouts depending on screen width: [Difference between sw600dp and w600dp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880746/difference-between-sw600dp-and-w600dp)

I think the only thing that should be the background image is the gas pump photo. Text should not be put in image because if the image is rescaled / stretched then the distortion will look horrible. So I would have RelativeLayout as root view, set with that photo. And then I would have two elements "Denko" and "Welcome" which can be TextView and ImageView wrapped in a layout. Then I would set `layout_above` for "Message" with "Denko"'s id. This way "Message" will always be above "Denko".

Comment: The message is a text placed inside a gradient rectangle so there should not be any rescaling problem with it. Even then the customer does not like any stretching of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can have different folders like layout-large and layout-medium just like you have drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, etc. This will change which layout file it uses based on the device. [For more reading checkout Google's training.](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSizeQuali)