# Android activity loads wrong layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing a simple app where you can see a list of musicians, and when you click on a musician, you get some details about it (genre, top hits and biography).
The functionality that I want to achieve is this: in case you're viewing it on a wide screen, let the list of musicians be on the left and the details should appear on the right (once a musician is clicked); if it's a narrow screen, the details should appear separately on a new screen. The functionality should be accomplished with fragments and Framelayouts.

So I have the `activity_main.xml`, and I went to *Add new resource file -> layout file* and I added `activity_main.xml (w600dp)` which I expect to automatically load on landscape-oriented smartphones or tablets.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/muzicari_lista"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**w600dp/activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lista_muzicara"></FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/detalji_muzicar"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

XML's of fragments that contain the list and the details are fairly simple with a few textblocks.
Here's the onCreate method of the mainActivity's class:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        unosi = new ArrayList<Muzicar>(); //let's presume there's something in this list


        wideL = false;
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        //fetching FragmentManager
        FrameLayout ldetalji = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.detalji_muzicar);
        if(ldetalji!=null){
//layout for wide screens
            wideL=true;
            FragmentDetalji fd;
            fd = (FragmentDetalji)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.detalji_muzicar);
//checking if there is FragmentDetalji already created:
            if(fd==null) {
                //if not, we're creating it now
                fd = new FragmentDetalji();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detalji_muzicar, fd).commit();
            }
        }

        FragmentLista fl = (FragmentLista)fm.findFragmentByTag("Lista");
//we're checking if there's already fl created

        if(fl==null){
            //if it hasn't been created:
            fl = new FragmentLista();
            Bundle argumenti = new Bundle();
            argumenti.putParcelableArrayList("Alista",unosi);
            fl.setArguments(argumenti);
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.muzicari_lista, fl).commit();
        }else{
            //case when we change from portrait to landscape, and there was FragmentDetalji already open

            fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
```

Classes `FragmentDetalji` and `FragmentLista` don't do much special besides utilizing `onCreateView` (though I can add them if they might be the source of the trouble).

The problem is that no matter what I use for loading this app, activity_main gets loaded in its default form, not the `w600dp` version! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your res folder structure screenshot.

Comment: @Shadab Ansari http://prntscr.com/alaq06
activity_pocetni = activity_main.

Comment: Please paste your Manifest file.

Comment: @Shadab Ansari
http://pastebin.com/H1TRbVB0

I can even send you the complete project, it's like 9MB.

Answer (score 0):

To provide alternative layout resources, you need to create a sub-directory inside your res folder named `layout-sw600dp` and place your altered layout in there, with the EXACT name as the other small screen layout. Then your Activity should automatically look in this folder. So if your xml file is titled `activity_main.xml` it should have the exact same name in the `layout-sw600dp` folder as well.

You can also supply alternate layouts for landscape by creating a sub-directory called `layout-land` or `layout-sw600dp-land` for large screen.

Also note that there are differences between using `sw600dp` and `w600dp` -- See this question for more info: [Difference between sw600dp and w600dp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880746/difference-between-sw600dp-and-w600dp)

Comment: Android Studio has done this for me automatically. I just don't get it why doesn't it get loaded.

Comment: If you are wanting the layout to change when the user rotates the screen, you need to use `layout-land` instead. If you are just wanting the layout to be different on larger screens, use `sw600dp` and not `w600dp`. See the question I linked in my answer for more info about the two.

Comment: I'm expecting it to work the same way on pretty much any screen that's wide enough, landscape smartphone is just an example, it can be a tablet as well or whatever.

Comment: Ah I see. The other thing I wanted to mention is that I noticed you are using separate `activity` and `content` xml files. Make sure you create alternate files for your `content` xml files as well. In your image, it looks like you only created separate resources for your `activity` xml files.