# 360dp is layout looks different on various phones

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

I have a folder in my android app labeled: values-sw360dp
I have tested this on different phones who's smallest width is 360:

```
Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
int x = (int)config.smallestScreenWidthDp;  //x = 360
```

but all these phones look different(some buttons are not on the screen) in spite of them having x = 360. How can I provide dimensions for these different phones?

I came across the following [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880746/difference-between-sw600dp-and-w600dp), and this [one](https://mcochin.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/android-screen-resolutions-and-their-width-in-dp/) which  and it stated there are different kinds of sw360... but I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

[res folder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeJRx.png)

In the res folder (app\src\main\res)
for layouts create folders layout/layout-sw***dp for different screen size, as shown in pic
then in the xml inside the layout/layout-sw***dp, define the views.

based on the screen size, android framework automatically refer associated xml layout file.

For eg if the device falls under sw360dp, then xml in layout-sw360dp will be used/inflated,

Similarly you can use values folder (as shown in pic), for eg  we can define different padding and margin values (if required) for different screen sizes.

Comment: tanni you are not getting it - hte problem is that there are many phones which fall under sw360 , they all look different because of some other factor. what is it and how do I handle it ?

Comment: if you could share your layout xml file please. Yes you are right, many phones will fall under sw360.

Comment: there really isnt anything worth seeing in my layout, here is an example of one button from the layout:   <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGoBackFromBattery"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/distance_between_battery_buttons"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GO BACK"
            android:textAllCaps="true"

            style="@style/provisioning_buttons"
         /> so how do you handle those other phones which fall under sw360?

Comment: thanks, complete xml file would have been more useful. The point to understand is even a 10inch tabler falls under sw360, as the condition sw sets is smallest width should be greater than 360dp. 

if the buttons or view is not getting displayed then I feel it has to do with layout view. For eg the button takes 210dp and imagine there are 3 such buttons in a row then  there combined width could be greater than device width.

If you could share the complete layout xml file it will help us.