# Difference between screen width and smallest screen width in dimens.xml

Tags: android, android-xml

What is the difference between Smallest screen width and Screen width in available qualifiers when creating the dimens resource file. How both of them affect the devices? Please clarify my doubt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a screen of `720X480` then smallest width is always 480 but screen width will be 480 if screen is in portrait and 720 if screen is in land scape . Screen width changes according to orientation .

Related answer from [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880838/6478047)

Comment: Oh. So we should always give smallest width rather than width right?