# dimens.xml for multi window mod

Tags: android, android-screen-support, multi-window

My app supports multi window feature. I want the app to take dimensions from different dimens.xml files when the app is in normal mode and multi window mode.

I have declared the minWidth = 255dp and minHeight = 600dp.

I have declared the dimens-h600dp.xml and dimens.xml files but the app takes the values from only dimens-h600dp.xml in any mode.

How can I make the  app to take dimensions from different dimens.xml files when the app is in normal mode and multi window mode ?

Comment: Log the `screenWidthDp` and `screenHeightDp` values from `Configuration` as you use your app, particularly as you switch between normal and split-screen mode. Do the values change? Do the values make sense for your device? How do those values line up with your resource set qualifiers (e.g,. `-h600dp`)?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes the values change when switched between normal and split-screen mode. yes the values make sense. I have dimens-w250dp and dimens.xml files. The app is taking the values from dimens-w250dp.xml   for both normal and split-screen modes

Comment: "I have dimens-w250dp and dimens.xml files" -- according to your question, you have `dimens-h600dp` and `dimens` files. So, which is it? Or do you have all three? In terms of `dimens-w250dp`, if you are holding your phone in portrait and enter split-screen mode, the width is not changing. And since most phones will be at least 250dp wide, `dimens-w250dp` would be what I expect Android to use.

Comment: @CommonsWare Apologies for the confusion. I have only dimens-w250dp and dimens.xml files. I have no issues in portrait mode. when the device is in landscape and split screen mode , I want the app to take the values from dimens-w250dp.xml when in landscape split screen mode.  Correct me if am doing something wrong.

Comment: OK, so to be clear: in landscape split-screen, is `Configuration` reporting a value for `screenWidthDp` that is lower than 250? If so... do you have an `android:configChanges` attribute on the `<activity>` element in the manifest for the activity that you are working on?

Comment: Yes , `Configuration` reporting a value for screenWidthDp that is lower than 250. I have `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout` in manifest for the activity.

Comment: You are specifically opting out of configuration changes for screen sizes. As a result, nothing will happen automatically to force you to take on new resource values when the app enters or exits split-screen mode. So, for "How can I make the app to take dimensions from different dimens.xml files", what exactly are you doing to take those new dimension values? Can you provide a [mcve] showing your code for your `onConfigurationChanged()` method, for example?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not overriding the `onConfigurationChanged()` .

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please help with this also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58623556/screen-gets-reduced-beyond-the-minimum-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifically opting out of configuration changes for screen sizes. As a result, nothing will happen automatically to force you to take on new resource values when the app enters or exits split-screen mode.

I recommend removing `android:configChanges`. Android will then recreate your activities and fragments when a configuration change occurs, and you will pick up the revised resources at that point.